# Why doesn't SKNode convertPoint:fromNode work between siblings?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, geometry, sknode

I'm trying to use the following [SKNode method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKNode/convertPoint:fromNode:):

```
public func convertPoint(point: CGPoint, fromNode node: SKNode) -> CGPoint
```

The method works as I'd expect in some situations, but not in others. For example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var sceneView: SKView!
    private var scene = SKScene()
    private var root = SKNode()
    private var node1 = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake(10, 10))
    private var node2 = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.blueColor(), size: CGSizeMake(10, 10))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        node1.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
        node2.anchorPoint = CGPointZero
        root.addChild(node1)
        root.addChild(node2)
        node1.position = CGPointMake(10, 10)
        node2.position = CGPointMake(20, 20)
        scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
        scene.addChild(root)
        sceneView.presentScene(scene, transition: SKTransition())
        print("position1 \(root.convertPoint(node2.position, toNode: node1))")
        print("position2 \(root.convertPoint(node1.position, toNode: node2))")
        print("position3 \(root.convertPoint(CGPointMake(0, 0), fromNode: node1))")
        print("position4 \(root.convertPoint(CGPointMake(0, 0), fromNode: node2))")
        print("position5 \(node1.convertPoint(CGPointMake(0, 0), fromNode: node2))")
        print("position6 \(node2.convertPoint(CGPointMake(0, 0), fromNode: node1))")
    }
}
```

[image]

This prints the following output:

```
position1 (10.0, 10.0)
position2 (-10.0, -10.0)
position3 (10.0, 10.0)
position4 (20.0, 20.0)
position5 (0.0, 0.0)
position6 (0.0, 0.0)
```

The first four outputs are as I'd expect, but I'm struggling to see how the last two are correct. Can anyone explain this?

(Xcode 7.1.1, iOS 9)

Comment: Its probably because the second argument states "Another node in the same node tree as this node.", and SpriteKit treats sibling nodes as being in separate "sub"-trees. So if A and B are siblings, A is not in the parent hierarchy of B and vice versa.